# BI Publisher 11.1.1.9.0 with JDK 8 on Weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: oracle11g, java-8, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, bi-publisher

I have installed OBIEE (v. 11.1.1.9.0) on Weblogic 10.3.6., extending an existing domain. My requirement is to use JDK 8.
When I start up the servers, the following error is encountered and BI fails to start. The error is while loading wsclient-rt.jar
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/io/CharacterEncoding
at oracle.j2ee.ws.common.util.TestPageUtils.encode(TestPageUtils.java:216)

After a research figured out that sun.io,CharacterEncoding is removed from JDK 8. I am aware that JDK 8 is not supported on Weblogic 10.3.6.
But, is there any way I could get the BI publisher running on Weblogic 10.3.6 using JDK 8 or is there any patch available for weblogic 10.3.6. supporting JDK 8?

Comment: Can you use [a later version of WLS](https://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/weblogic_server_12_1_3)?

Comment: No, we want to test our app with WL v.10.3.6 with JDK 8.
Would replacing the problematic jars in v. 10.3.6. (wsclient-rt .. etc) with those from WL v. 12.1.3, supported by JDK 8, work? Or is there any other way?

Comment: That version of OBIEE isn't supported with JDK 8 either ([requirements](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi/bi-11gr1certmatrix-11-1-1-9-0-2541437.xls), via [supported configurations](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/fusion-certification-100350.html)). You seem to have conflicting requirements if you're restricted to older middleware but want to use JDK 8.

Comment: Are there patches or is there a newer version of OBIEE supporting JDK 8?
Couldn't find any patches. 12c version seems to in closed-beta stage. Any ideas?